# Plain text url on HTML mail without be active

Tags: html, url, html-email, plaintext

I want to put one URL as a plaint text. That url could not be an active link (secure policies :S). The problem is when I send an email with that plain text some email services like Microsoft(@hotmail, @outlook, @live) recognize my plain text and convert to an active link. I use the following to cheat microsoft, google, etc but now it doesn't work and i can only use Html code to fix it.

```
<p>
<strong>
h
<input type="hidden" name="blank"/>
t
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
t
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
p:
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
//w
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
w
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
w
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
.
<wbr/>
myawesomelink.
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
c
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
o
<img width="0" height="0" alt=""/>
m?cn=
<wbr/>
T007
</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: ex. http://www.myawesomelink.com?cn=T007 The problem is not the link I use some generic. The problem is how to tag that plain text or use something that email services don't transform my plain text into active link.

Comment: In my code i use some hidden images (width 0 height 0) to separate my plain text and in the mail appear correct all the text together but in the recent weeks Microsoft kills my idea and active my plain text

Comment: send it as `http://myawesomelink%2Ecom?cn=T007` )) But some browsers may not treat this as well as major browsers does

Comment: The problem is that you are modifying the information of the link, I want it inactive but with the correct information.

Comment: then seems like no way here